# How can I cleanly override the default ServiceLocator used by Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am developing an application that uses Jersey (2.5) as its REST front-end, and Jetty as embedded HTTP(S) server, both in a so-called "embedded" way, eg. without resorting to making `.war`  and deploying it but through programmatic configuration of handlers, resources, injections...

I would like to somehow override the HK2 `ServiceLocator` that is used on the server side by Jersey, or possibly provide this service locator with a parent for resolving dependencies that are defined outside of the REST part of the application. From what I see of the code, this does not seem possible: The ServiceLocator is instantiated inside the `ApplicationHandler` through a call to `Injections`:

```
if (customBinder == null) {
        this.locator = Injections.createLocator(new ServerBinder(application.getProperties()), new ApplicationBinder());
    } else {
        this.locator = Injections.createLocator(new ServerBinder(application.getProperties()), new ApplicationBinder(),
                                                customBinder);
    }
```

And the code in Injections tells me the following:

```
 public static ServiceLocator createLocator(Binder... binders) {
    return _createLocator(null, null, binders);
 }
```

which means the newly created service locator has some arbitrarily generated name and has no parent.

Is there a (clean) way to change this behaviour so that I inject my own ServiceLocator as a parent of the application's?

Comment: Why can't you just add your services to the Jersey ServiceLocator?

Comment: Because my services are discovered/wired before I start the container. There is a service loader that loads "modules" with DI stuff and I would like these modules to be able to contribute resources without depending on HK2, although it is currently implemented in HK2 behind the scene. I really do not understand why this is so hard in Jersey.

Comment: At first I thought you could use AliasDescriptors, but I think there is a little feature needed here to make this work better.  I am looking into make this easier.

Comment: What i am doing now which really I am not proud of is overloading th Injections class at source level to inject a parent ServiceLocator.

Comment: Is your base service locator something that I should also keep track of dynamically?  I ask because I can easily create a utility that copies the current set of services from one locator to another (via an Alias, not actually do a copy) or I can create a JIT resolver which would work better if your base locator can change services over time, but which would then only work for Injections, and not for raw lookups.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Is it not possible to provide a ServiceLocator upon construction of ResourceConfig that would be used as base for resolving dependencies?

Comment: @jwells131313 have you, by any chance, implemented this feature? I attempted to implement it externally but neither was able to find getting the list of descriptors out of a ServiceLocator nor understand how to create an AliasDescriptor out of an existing descriptor.

Comment: We worked around the problem a different way.  It shouldn't be difficult to get all descriptors from one ServiceLocator and mirror them in another.  In particular there is a method BuilderHelper.allFilter that can be passed into getAllServices(Filter f) that'll get you all services in a ServiceLocator.  From there it shouldn't be too difficult to add all the services from one services into the other ServiceLocator.  The feature that might have made doing this possible with a JIT resolver is https://java.net/jira/browse/HK2-170.  We've deferred implementing that due to some security concerns

Comment: I have also added this: https://java.net/jira/browse/HK2-242 to track the overall request, which is to mirror one ServiceLocator's services in another ServiceLocator

Answer (score 6):

I know that this answer is a little late. I struggled with the same issue, but in the Dropwizard framework. After some debugging, I saw the some lines of code which made me happy!

```
final ServiceLocator locator = (ServiceLocator) webConfig.getServletContext()
            .getAttribute(ServletProperties.SERVICE_LOCATOR);
```

This piece of code is inside of the jerseyes WebComponent constuctor. So the solution is to provide `ServletProperties.SERVICE_LOCATOR` to your ServletContext. In the Dropwizard environment, I achieved it by doing

```
environment.getApplicationContext().getAttributes().setAttribute(ServletProperties.SERVICE_LOCATOR, locator);
```

Comment: I wonder if DropWizard do not ressort to the same kind of hack I had to do internally, so that it exposes the locator to you.

Answer (score 3):

We have a similar set up, and I've managed to get our architecture working using jwells131313's new [bridgeServiceLocator](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b10/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/extras/ExtrasUtilities.html#bridgeServiceLocator%28org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator,%20org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator%29) API.

*EDIT : Note that the current HK2 bridging implementation means Singleton instances are only local to the ServiceLocator they are created in, meaning that bridged architectures can contain more than one instance of a Singleton service. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293388/how-do-i-make-a-hk2-servicelocator-use-the-singleton-service-instances-from-the) for more information and a possible workaround/alternative approach.*

*EDIT #2 : The aforementioned bug in the ServiceLocator bridge has been fixed. The fix will be in hk2 2.5.0-b07 or later*

Basically I created a `Feature` implementation to set up the bridging and registered it with Jersey (in our instance via the `ServletContainer`).

```
public class InjectionBridge implements Feature
{
  private static ServiceLocator _applicationServiceLocator;

  private final ServiceLocator _serviceLocator;

  @Inject
  private InjectionBridge(ServiceLocator serviceLocator)
  {
    _serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean configure(FeatureContext context)
  {
    if (_applicationServiceLocator != null)
      ExtrasUtilities.bridgeServiceLocator(_serviceLocator, _applicationServiceLocator);
    return true;
  }

  public static void setApplicationServiceLocator(ServiceLocator applicationServiceLocator)
  {
    _applicationServiceLocator = applicationServiceLocator;
  }
}
```

`setApplicationServiceLocator` is then called from the application code with the `ServiceLocator` created by the application to manage the application resources.

This means that Jersey RESTful service implementations can now simply declare fields with the `@Inject` annotation and access those injected resources to service requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can not make one ServiceLocator the parent of another after the ServiceLocator has been created.

However as of hk2 2.4.0-b11 there will be the ability to have a ServiceLocator -> ServiceLocator bridge.  Thus all the services from your ServiceLocator can be put into the ServiceLocator of Jersey (or any other ServiceLocator).  This is the API: [bridgeServiceLocator](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b10/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/extras/ExtrasUtilities.html#bridgeServiceLocator%28org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator,%20org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator%29).  It is in the hk2-extras module of hk2.

There is a version of this available in hk2 2.4.0-b10 that should work, the fully tested and documented feature will be in hk2 2.4.0-b11

Comment: jwells131313 I have run into an issue using this bridge, [outlined in this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293388/how-do-i-make-a-hk2-servicelocator-use-the-singleton-service-instances-from-the). I would appreciate any feedback you can give.