# ContainerRequestFilter with per-lookup-injectable not injected per request

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, hk2

I use Jersey 2 on a standalone Grizzly webserver. HK2 is used for CDI. I'd like to get a service with `@PerLookup`-scope injected into a jersey `ContainerRequestFilter`.

The service:

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.PerLookup;
import org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Service;

@Service
@PerLookup
public class SessionManager {

    [...]
}
```

The filter:

```
import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
@PreMatching
public class HttpSessionFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Inject
    private javax.inject.Provider<org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request> requestProvider;

    @Inject
    private SessionManager sessionManager;

    [...]

}
```

My problem is this:

- the filter is instantiated once (at startup)
- the service is injected once (at filter-startup)
- everything downstream from there is happening effectively at singleton scope

Question: how can I get the service injected per-request?

**Update**

The suggested approach using `@Inject javax.inject.Provider<SessionManager> sessionManagerProvider` makes logical sense to me, but `sessionManagerProvider.get()` returns null.

The hk2 serviceLocator is populated through the inhabitant-generator. It reports:

```
SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=com.skalio.skaliopush.http.SessionManager
    contracts={com.skalio.skaliopush.http.SessionManager}
    scope=org.glassfish.hk2.api.PerLookup
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=null
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=31
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=494317290
    reified=false)
```

And if I add the explicit binding, then it is also found like this:

```
SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=com.skalio.skaliopush.http.SessionManager
    contracts={com.skalio.skaliopush.http.SessionManager}
    scope=org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder$2@78b729e6
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=39
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=2041416495
    reified=false)
```

**2nd Update**

I am using two service locators: One created explicitly, and populated through the HK2 inhabitant generator; and the one that Jersey creates. They are joined through a [BridgingInjectionResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31348557/295962).

@peeskillet's response works, when I add the explicit binding to Jersey's service locator. Adding the binding to the other service locator results in the above (`sessionManagerProvider.get()` returns null).

Comment: Not sure exactly where you are performing the bridging, but what happens if you just pass the one using the generator straight to the [`GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(url, resourceConfig, locator)`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.18/jersey/index.html?org/glassfish/jersey/grizzly2/httpserver/GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.html)? Or is that what you are currently doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you also use `javax.inject.Provider<SessionMananger>`. The default scope is per lookup. But I guess you need to load it lazily.

Not sure how it differs functionally from `RequestScoped` in Jersey. I thought that in a `PerLookup` scope, it would get created twice if I inject it once into the filter and once into the resource class, but just testing right now, even in `PerLookup` scope, it was still only created once for each request.

Alternatively, just to be sure, you may just want to bind it in a `RequestScoped` if that is what you really want.

```
register(new AbstractBinder(){
    protected void configure() {
        bind(SessionManager.class).to(SessionManager.class)
                                  .in(RequestScoped.class);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I must be doing something wrong. I've updated the question, maybe this helps to drill down further?

Comment: Like I said I tested it and it works fine. There's nothing you're showing above  that is different from what I used, besides making the changes I mentioned. Maybe it's something you're not showing, like how you create the application and server. I don't know. Can't say what I can't reproduce